# Как проверить в Scanner символ? Изящнее?

Tags: input, java

Доброго времени суток.
Хочу вводить в консоль строки и потом с ними работать. 
Но не могу понять как мне сделать условие с помощью которого обрывать цикл ввода, допустим с помощью какого то символа. И можно ли это сделать с помощью класса Scanner, или надо посимвольный ввод использовать? Конечно можно сделать с помощью equals и сравнить следующую строку с символом, а есть более изящное решение?

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class IInConsole {

    public void start() throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = null;
        String a = null;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (true) {
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            a = sc.nextLine();
            if(a.equals("-1")){
                break;
            }
            sb.append(a + "\n");
        }

        System.out.println(sb);

    }
}
```

Comment: Хм. Вы в цикле аллоцируете каждый раз новый сканер. Учитывая возможную буферизацию, это может привести к непредсказуемым эффектам.

Я бы сканер входного потока объявил синглтоном.

Comment: А вынести sc = new Scanner(System.in); будет не лучше?

Comment: @steelhouse: Ну или так. Но тогда проблема будет между последовательными вызовами `IIConsole.start()`, думайте сами.